# Let $A$ and $B$ be two nilpotent matrices. Prove that $A+B$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two nilpotent matrices. Prove that $A+B$ is nilpotent.

I'm new to the study of matrices, I already proved that $AB$ is nilpotent too (that was the previous question) but I have no clue about solving this one.
Plus, I was wondering if I have to prove that it exists an $n$ such that $(A+B)^n=0$ or such that $A^n+B^n=0$.

Any help?

EDIT:

I just know that:
$(A+B)^k=(A+B)(A+B)...(A+B)$ $k$ times, so I need to prove that $(A+B)=0$

Is this enough to prove what I need, right?

Comment: $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$ are nilpotent.

Comment: $(A+B)^n \neq A^n + B^n$.  If you are wanting to show that $C$ is nilpotent that means you want to show that there is some $n$ such that $C^n$ is nilpotent.  Replacing $C$ by $(A+B)$ that says that if you want to show that $(A+B)$ is nilpotent that you want to find some $n$ such that $(A+B)^n$ is nilpotent.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ commute, then this is true by the binomial theorem. Otherwise, there are counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A^m=0,B^n=0.$

Then 
$$(A+B)^{m+n}=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n} C_{m+n}^k A^{m+n-k}B^{k}$$
provided AB=BA.

When $k<n$, we know $m+n-k>m$, which means $A^{m+n-k}=0$. And when $k\geq n$, we know $B^k=0.$
That is $(A+B)^{m+n}=0,$ which means A+B is nilpotent.

But I have no idea how to answer it  if $AB\neq BA$.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I didn't understand why when $k>n$ we know that $B^k=0$?

Comment: @Schiele Ling says in the first line that B^n=0.

Answer (score 3):

Take for example the nilpotent matrices

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\4&-2\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\;B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\implies\text{ what is}\;\;A+B \;?$$

Why that sum can't be nilpotent ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I mean, I know what matrix $A+B$ is, but how is this related to the fact of being nilpotent or not?

Comment: @Schiele $A+B$ is invertible and an invertible matrix cannot be nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a hypothesis: the group of the matrices has to be commutative! Otherwise the thesis doesn't hold:

let 
$
A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$
B=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

We have that $A^2=0$ and $B^2=0$, but $(A+B)^2=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$
 which is definitely not the zero matrix!